# Select all in lambda Where()

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

I know that this works:

```
var result = someCollection.Select(x=>x);
```

I'm after a similar result with the `Where()` method:

```
var result = someCollection.Where(x=> someBool ? x : x.Key == 1);
```

I would like to select "everything" if `someBool` is true. The code above doesn't work. Is there any way to solve this using lambda?

Comment: Not sure what you want. Perhaps `someBool || x.Key == 1`.

Comment: The answers below will work, but could you just add your where clause in an if statement (i.e. not add it at all if `someBool` is true)?

Comment: What linq provider is this? If it's `Linq-To-Objects` you should consider to use a simple `if`-clause for `someBool`. Otherwise you're looping the entire collection even if you know that you want all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `||` operator, if `someBool` is true, it will select all the records.

```
var result = someCollection.Where(x=> someBool || x.Key == 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the conditional-`OR` operator

```
var result = someCollection.Where(x => someBool || x.Key == 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could alternatively do,

```
var result = someCollection;

if (someBool)
{
    result = someCollection.Where(x => x.Key == 1);
}
```

I think the extra typing improves the readability of the code and could improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

This is Tested code

```
var result = someCollection.Where(x => someBool || x.Key == 1);
```

Comment: I dont see your post i have tried by my own and post it.But after posting i see that some peoples are also share same.You are also right

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using `||` inside `Where`'s predicate it's sometimes useful to only apply the `Where` if it's needed.

```
var result = source;
if(!someBool)
  result = result.Where(x => x.Key == 1);
```

This is usually a bit faster since it doesn't need to filter at all. But it exposes `source` to the outside, which is sometimes undesirable.

Comment: +1, I'd prefer this myself if there's no good reason not to do it this way. (It's a shame `AsEnumerable` doesn't help here.)